# Server Performance Monitoring - slowest Compoent

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, newrelic

I am using JMeter for my application performance testing. I use New Relic for monitoring.  JBoss is the app server.

Sometimes I get below items listed as the slowest component in NewRelic. I do not get any other info.

Does anyone have any idea what needs to be done in this case?

`com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase`

`com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase`

`com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhas`

Please leave a comment if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have good monitoring and analysis around this:

Start with following:

1. Check the throughput of the requests, and see what requests have high response time.
2. While you are running tests, take thread dumps to see if there any threads blocked, also enable slow query log in case mysql or look into db for heavy queries.
3. Check for CPU and memory utilization using commands like sar or vmstat.
4. Check for the connection pool settings.

This should give you better idea about the bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks. I use NewRelic which is famous. however the tool shows above classes take too much time thats what i dont understand.

Comment: @KitKarson Those classes are all from sun libraries, you need to find to who is making calls to these libraries and further investigate around it.